# Mysql insert slow on specific table in kohana

Tags: php, mysql, performance, kohana

I have a simple insert query of 1 row into a table. It is taking 10 seconds to insert.

Analysis results:

1. The problem exists only in that table name.
2. An external script to insert to that table is fast.
3. Problem exists within kohana.
4. I am also using sphinx indexing for search.

Comment: Did you had a look into mysql.log if both queries are 100% same

Comment: And connection too? tcp or socket?

Comment: Are you sure that the issue is the insert and not the rest of your code trying to load something that takes longer than it needs to? Have you done any benchmark around the specific code that does the insert? Have you tried using a local phpMyAdmin to see if the same happens?

Comment: Yes, tried a lot. The above results are very true. PHPmyadmin takes normal time. Simple php script takes normal time.Only when that mysql_query statement is in kohana, it takes a load of time.

Comment: then I will take my guess the problem is not the insert code on konoha but rather something you have loading taking longer. Try using firebug or similar tool and see if anything seems to be hanging on the NET tab load.

Comment: But when commented the insert query, kohana is fast.

Comment: What is the table name? Can you reproduce it on another machine?

Comment: Table name is 'vehicles', I made a similar table with different name and insertion is working fine. Reproduce means?

Comment: @Prix When i turned on profiler, the server hanged like hell.

Comment: @user3837211 When you put exactly the same script on another server, does the behaviour persist?